# How to have Wordpress & Sinatra (or similar) coexist?

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, sinatra

The homepage of my site is a Wordpress blog, but I'd also like to do some non-PHP server-side programming on some special URL's and subdirectories of the root. Is it possible to have Flask or Sinatra or another web framework coexist with Wordpress? I'm using Apache on Webfaction at the moment.

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much anything in Wordpress goes through a mod_rewrite redirect to a single PHP script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

as long as your other systems can coexist with this rewriting (either by using actual real scripts, or rewrites that don't trigger the WP stuff), you should be fine.